# How can stop change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var InDate = trim($(".inDate").val());

if (InDate == '') {
  $(".inDate").val(dateDisplayFormat);
}

//Bind date picker
daymarker.bindElement(".inDate",
    { 
        onSelect: function(date) {
            $(".inDate").trigger('change');            
        }, 
        dateFormat:jsDateFormat
    });

$(".inDate").change(function() {
  //some validation functions are called here.
});
```

Lets say that i have two rows with indate and outdates.

for example:

```
Indate       outDate
2011-02-20    2011-02-24 
2011-02-25    2011-02-27
```

so when i change the first date using the date picker indate change will be called twice.so because of the it is not possible to give the validation message.Lets say my first date is wrong.and second date is correct.because of that validation message will get hidden.

Is there a way that i can stop the second trigger if the first date is wrong???

Answer (score 0):

It's not that it's "called twice", it's that you're using `$(".inDate")` multiple times, which always refers to the full collection of matching elements, not just the one you happen to be interested in at the time.

This is probably closer to what you intended:

```
// loop through each matching element
$(".inDate").each(function(index, elem){

  var

    // this particular element
    $elem = $(elem),

    InDate = trim($elem.val());

  if (InDate === '') {
    $elem.val(dateDisplayFormat);
  }

  //Bind date picker
  daymarker.bindElement(elem, { 
    onSelect: function(date) {
      $elem.trigger('change');            
    }, 
    dateFormat:jsDateFormat
  });

  $elem.change(function() {
    //some validation functions are called here.
  });

});
```

I assume that `daymarker.bindElement` is smart enough to allow an actual DOM element as its first argument, and doesn't specifically require a string containing a CSS seletor.

I also assume that `daymarker.bindElement` can be called any number of times, with different target DOM elements each time.  If that's not the case, then by all means create a new `daymarker` inside the `.each()` iterator function.